# JavaScript selecting HTMLInputElement worked when I didnt expect it to

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following HTML page, where I need to provide the input value from `HTMLInputElement` into the `mine` JavaScript function.

```
<input id="input">
<span>
    <button onclick="mine(input)">Mine!</button>
</span>

mine: function (input) {
    alert(input.value);
},
```

I intended to pass the control Id into the function, then find and manipulate the control. I thought I would need to use something like `document.getElementById` or its `JQuery` equivalent.

However I was surprised to find that I was just able to use `input.value`.

How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the *id* is being used as a property on `window` (the global object) which points at the node with the id.

You can read the spec on it [**here**](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object)

It isn't recommended to use this behaviour as it's more a *"feature"* for legacy support and can give unexpected results if you have a conflict with another variable, e.g. if you used the *id* `"top"` or if you have another node with a *name attribute* which matches first.

- The result may also be a *HTMLCollection* rather than a *HTMLElement*.
- If there is not already an identifier for the value (e.g. you `var`d it or it's a native thing like `alert`) the result will be the first match from

  1. A child window's *name*
  2. All nodes with the *name* attribute with this value

     - If just one node, returns that node. Otherwise returns a *HTMLCollection*.
  3. The node with the *id* attribute with this value

As you can see, this behaviour could easily give an unexpected result so

### **don't use it**.